# Puppet7 agent can't find catalog from server

Tags: puppet

I'm learning Puppet now. Everything is new to me... After installed a puppet7 server and agent on my two learning VMs--
192.168.160.131   puppet-mst.eisen   #The puppet server
192.168.160.140   sles12.eisen       #The puppet agent
And I've successfully signed the node "sles12.eisen" to the server "puppet-mst.eisen" --

```
[root@puppet-mst manifests]# puppetserver --version
puppetserver version: 7.4.1
[root@puppet-mst manifests]# puppetserver ca list --all
Signed Certificates:
    puppet-mst.eisen       (SHA256)  0B:3F:DA:60:2F:2D:D3:91:94:58:E2:B6:32:28:50:8E:D4:1C:A0:8F:A0:CF:94:99:6E:EE:99:46:B4:1D:30:58   alt names: ["DNS:puppet-mst.eisen"]      authorization extensions: [pp_cli_auth: true]
    puppet-mst             (SHA256)  C8:89:47:D2:15:74:6E:49:E7:9A:27:B5:EA:10:9B:81:C4:DC:68:E8:B4:01:07:5D:63:34:5A:AF:B6:66:C9:EE   alt names: ["DNS:puppet-mst"]
    sles12.eisen           (SHA256)  C5:40:D7:8A:C6:64:BD:E8:BF:D3:BB:5D:01:24:66:03:57:96:84:31:84:42:DF:36:AA:D1:25:14:76:4D:A5:99   alt names: ["DNS:sles12.eisen"]
```

Then I wrote a testing module --filetest1, and hope it can put a file to the agent node in /tmp/puppettest --

```
[root@puppet-mst manifests]# cat /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/filetest1/manifests/init.pp
class filetest1{
file {'/tmp/puppettest/filetest1':
ensure => file,
content => 'Hello World!',
}
}
[root@puppet-mst manifests]# cat /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp
node 'sles12.eisen'{
    include filetest1

}
```

But the "puppet agent --test" can't work, it's said it either server can't find agent node, or the test module's catalog is missing --

```
sles12:/tmp/puppettest # puppet --version
7.12.0
sles12:/tmp/puppettest # hostname -f
sles12.eisen
sles12:/tmp/puppettest # puppet agent --test --verbose
Info: Using environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Failed when searching for node sles12.eisen: Failed to find sles12.eisen via exec: Execution of '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/node.rb sles12.eisen' returned 1:
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

I don't know what's wrong here. Please kind help. Thanks

Regards
Eisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests that you have configured Puppet to use an [external node classifier](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/nodes_external.html) (`/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/node.rb`), and either the attempt to execute it is failing altogether, or it is terminating with a failure status, or it is not outputting anything.

You may want to explore ENCs later, but now is probably not the time for that.  To disable use of an ENC, edit `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf` and either remove the `node_terminus` setting or change its value to `plain`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes. Per your answer, I tested that '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/node.rb sles12.eisen' on the puppetserver and find the error is on Foreman-- I think it's due to the last foreman installation is incomplete -- And since I can't uninstall foreman clean. So now I've reinstalled the entire puppetserver VM -- and this time I didn't manage to install foreman only keep puppetserver and puppet-agent installed. Now it works fine. Thanks a lot again.